# Pip wont let me download any library in Python

Tags: python

```
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using 
"c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\python.exe" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\Scripts\pip.exe" install pandas: 
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

This is the error I get when I try and install something.

Comment: You have either not installed python or pip correctly.

Comment: execute `c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\python.exe -m pip install pandas`

Answer (score 0):

Oh. You call the command `sudo pip install packagenme`

or `sudo pip3 install packagename`

You forgot to call pip

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210299/discussion-on-answer-by-clement-tong-pip-wont-let-me-download-any-library-in-pyt).